# Can't get output from kwin script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde-plasma

I just installed kubuntu so that I could learn more about linux and I thought a kwin script would be a fun first project. Unfortunately, I got stuck immediately. I'm not actually able to see any output from my script and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here's all I did:

```
print("hello world");

function hello() {
  print("hello world");
}

registerShortcut("Hello", "Print hello world.", "Meta+R", hello);
```

I set QT_LOGGING_RULES as mentioned here: https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/kwin/ I also added it to .bash_profile and relogged.

I'm running journalctl -g "js:" -f but I'm not seeing any output. I also tried -g "hello".

I installed the script using kpackagetool5 --type=KWin/Script -i ~/.scripts/myscript and enabled it using the gui in settings. It shows up correctly there.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My js file was in script/contents, it should've been in script/contents/code.